# Can't install apk from uri on Android 10 in Eclipse projects

Tags: java, android, cordova

We are installing apk from file uri, its working upto Android Pie(9) ,in Android 10 mobile its showing **"There was  problem while Parsing"**. we have stored file in the application storage only and the build version is 4.4

I have shared the code below.

```
String PATH = Objects.requireNonNull(this.myActivity.getExternalFilesDir(null)).getAbsolutePath();
                 File file = new File(PATH + "/"+Utils.apk_name);
                 intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                 Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.myActivity, this.myActivity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
                 //Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(uri, "FileProvider.getUriForFi…eProvider.install\", file)");
                 intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Provider in Manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="com.kirubha.helpers.ESEProvider"          
        android:authorities="com.kirubha.provider" 
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

provider_paths

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path
    name="external_storage_root"
    path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: What has ESEProvider to do with FileProvider?

Comment: `<external-path` for getExternalFilesDir() you should use `<external-files-path`.

Comment: And... interesting... that you still use Eclipse!

Comment: `ACTION_VIEW` was deprecated for app installation. https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/AppInstaller shows how to use `PackageInstaller`, which is the longer-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found most of my file provider worries disapear when I add

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder buildervm = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(buildervm.build());
```

to my main activities.

The above was found in this answer which might be useful to you.

[android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

Comment: You should not advice such nasty tricks and propagate and write normal code instead.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 10, `ACTION_VIEW` is deprecated, need to use PackageInstaller instead.

Follow the below code to implement `PackageInstaller` in Java.

```
private static int REQUEST_OEN_DOCUMENT = 1337;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                            intent1.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                            intent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                            startActivityForResult(intent1, REQUEST_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                        }
```

This code will redirect to the files folder. Then need to select the .apk file.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_OEN_DOCUMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();

                   installAfterQ(uri);

                }
            }
        }

    }


public void installAfterQ(Uri uri) {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                InputStream inputStream = getApplication().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

                long length = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(getApplication(), uri).length();
                PackageInstaller installer = getApplication().getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
                PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
                int sessionId = installer.createSession(params);
                PackageInstaller.Session session = installer.openSession(sessionId);

                File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                OutputStream outputStream = session.openWrite(file.getName(), 0, length);

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buf, 0, (int) len);
                }


                session.fsync(outputStream);

                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), UpdateReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplication(), 3439, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                session.commit(pi.getIntentSender());
                session.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Update Receiver Class:

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

int status = intent.getIntExtra(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);

if (status == PackageInstaller.STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION) {
Intent activityIntent =intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT);
    context.startActivity(activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
} else if (status == PackageInstaller.STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {

     String msg =intent.getStringExtra(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS_MESSAGE);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Error while installing" + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


    }
}
```

Android Manifest.xml

Inside Application tag.

```
<receiver android:name=".UpdateReceiver"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.android.packageinstaller.notification.smallIcon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_install_notification" />
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Try this code. Hope this code is helpful.